# Apply j for two sets of i and by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
dt=data.table(ID=rep(1:6,each=2),Set=c("a","b"),Value=rnorm(12))
```

I'd like a data.table solution that the result is this:

```
dt.test=data.table(ID=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),ID],Value=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value]-dt[Set=="b",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value])
```

but I don't want to have to call `dt` twice in order to make `Value-Value`.

any help woud be appreciated.

Comment: Can I assume that each ID occurs exactly twice and is in the right order? A `shift` would be natural then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` to process values of the same column in different subsequent rows:

```
dt[, .(Value = Value - shift(Value, type = "lead")), by = ID][!is.na(Value), ]
```

results in

```
   ID      Value
1:  1  0.7455129
2:  2 -0.1529171
3:  3 -1.0823840
4:  4  1.5533354
5:  5 -1.2234450
6:  6 -0.5912473
```

Benchmark (kudos to @Wimpel for providing the code base!):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ricardo.solution = data.table(ID=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),ID],Value=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value]-dt[Set=="b",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value]),
  YOLO.solution = {df.test <- dcast(data = dt, ID ~ Set, value.var = 'Value')
  df.test <- df.test[, Values := a - b][,.(ID, Values)]},
  this.answer = dt[ dt[, .I[1], ID ]$V1][, `:=`(Set = NULL, Value = Value - dt[dt[, .I[2], ID ]$V1]$Value)][],
  shift = dt[, .(Value = Value - shift(Value, type = "lead")), by = ID][!is.na(Value), ]
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 ricardo.solution 4580.061 4992.562 5328.8262 5285.678 5473.8425 7620.749   100
    YOLO.solution 2272.906 2493.514 2739.5670 2635.498 2779.4650 4996.913   100
      this.answer 1343.026 1446.103 1546.7915 1517.141 1630.6945 2374.776   100
            shift  559.784  601.365  666.5094  629.343  665.7745 2201.881   100
```

Please note that the benchmark is not very representative for this small amount of input data...

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
# reshape the data table
df.test <- dcast(data = dt, ID ~ Set, value.var = 'Value')

# create new column
df.test <- df.test[, Values := a - b][,.(ID, Values)]
```

Comment: Reshape is not really a data.table solution. And the second one would give me a dt with the same size, which is not what I want it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should run this code, it gives exact same answer as expected in your question.

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos `dcast` **is** a `data.table` solution in this case since it is overwritten, see `?data.table::dcast`

Comment: @R Yoda, I didn't know that dcast had a data.table version. Thank you. And, I'm sorry, @YOLO, I guess I haven't properly looked at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

the fastest solution so far:

```
dt[ dt[, .I[1], ID ]$V1][, `:=`(Set = NULL, Value = Value - dt[dt[, .I[2], ID ]$V1]$Value)][]
```

**benchmarks**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ricardo.solution = data.table(ID=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),ID],Value=dt[Set=="a",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value]-dt[Set=="b",Value,by=ID][order(ID),Value]),
  YOLO.solution = {df.test <- dcast(data = dt, ID ~ Set, value.var = 'Value')
                   df.test <- df.test[, Values := a - b][,.(ID, Values)]},
  this.answer = dt[ dt[, .I[1], ID ]$V1][, `:=`(Set = NULL, Value = Value - dt[dt[, .I[2], ID ]$V1]$Value)][]
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# ricardo.solution 5.197409 5.338703 6.024780 5.526993 5.748874 45.018507   100
#    YOLO.solution 2.617082 2.719060 3.006002 2.784585 2.948021 17.891175   100
#      this.answer 1.432812 1.479057 1.525045 1.502857 1.539461  1.896759   100
```